# java_arguments in applet deployment is passed in base64

Tags: java, deployment, applet, web-deployment

I discovered, that `java_arguments` parameter is passed to applet as base64 encoded string. For example:

I deploy applet using something like that:

```
<object id="appletId">
...
<param name="java_arguments" value="-Xss4m" />
<param name="java-vm-args" value="-Xss4m" />
</object>
```

and when I try get these parameters in applet, I get:

```
String args1 = this.getParameter("java-vm-args"); // is "-Xss4m"
String args2 = this.getParameter("java_arguments"); // is "LVhzczRt" - base64 encoded value
```

I'm passing other arguments to an applet but nothing else is encoded. I tried find some informations, but I've failed. Do you know what happens and why?

Comment: Note:  In a [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) deployed applet, there are properties like `initial-heap-size` & `max-heap-size`.  I would use those over JVM args.